# WYSIWYG TinyMCE add Custom Javascript

Tags: javascript, theming, wysiwyg, tooltips

So I am running into the issue where I can't add any custom javascript to elements inside the WYSIWYG because its an iFrame. Is there some special way of adding custom javascript.

The main thing I want to accomplish is adding a custom tooltip to img elements that have a title attribute.

I tried things like hook_wysiwyg_editor_settings_alter to add a js file with my custom code.

I have also tried doing some custom css to accomplish like using :hover, :before, and :after but found out that sometimes this doesn't work well on images on various browsers.

Any ideas on what a good solution would be for this problem? Might have to create a custom plugin that doesn't have a button that imports javascript, I wonder if that could work?